# google map api V2 cilck my button to show MyLocation instead of default button

Tags: android, api, button

With Google Map API V1, I can create my own button then click the button to show mylocation.

But Google Map API V2, I only can use the default button created by

```
mMap.setMyLationEnabled(true);
```

to show mylation.

What can I do to use my own button to show MyLation just like click the default button 
created by

```
 mMap.setMyLationEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a button on mainActivity layout. the button will appear on map. The main Activity layout is something like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
        android:name="com.ftravelbook.ui.fragments.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="tag_fragment_map" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeView"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View" />
</FrameLayout>
```

then add code inside to process

```
LatLng myLocation =new LatLng(...);
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLocation , 13));
```